# Cannot do HTTP PUT action in NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Hi I am trying to Http PUT method in NSURLConnection.
I am posting data file to an amazon s3 path.

```
  -(void)postFaceVideo{

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://face_video.s3.amazonaws.com/chunks/?AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEY&Expires=1424373411&Signature=MYSIGNATURE"]];


 [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
 [request setHTTPBody:appDelegate.faceData];  // This is the saved NSData
 [request setTimeoutInterval:200];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
      }


    }
```

Before it was working fine, but now neither data is posted in the server nor any response is coming. What could be the reason?

Is there any change in these method in Xcode 6, because previously it worked fine when I was working with Xcode 5.

Also I have tried with NSURLSession as follows.

```
  -(void)postFaceVideo2{

      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://face_video.s3.amazonaws.com/chunks/?AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEY&Expires=1424373411&Signature=MYSIGNATURE"]];


    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.faceData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    request.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
    request.HTTPBody = appDelegate.faceData;


    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                              {
      if (!error)
    {

      NSLog(@"Status code: %i", ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode);

     NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;

            }
    else
        {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                    }
             }];

  [task resume];

 }
```

Here I am getting the error as -

```
         Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x171cadb0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://video_test.s3.amazonaws.com/chunks_dev/21662/facescan_1?Signature= MYSIGN =&Expires=1424381789&AWSAccessKeyId=MYID, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://video_test.s3.amazonaws.com/chunks_dev/21662/facescan_1?Signature=MYSIGN=&Expires=1424381789&AWSAccessKeyId=MYID, NSUnderlyingError=0x171b30c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)"}
```

Comment: Error  is   kCFURLErrorTimedOut = -1001,  why is your far end timing out? . Is your aws instance still happy?

Comment: So is that the issue with server ?

Comment: You have said "yo server" , the server hasn't said "yo client" back. Exactly why that is happening is up to you to find out.